# How to set the whole column to the index of the row

Tags: r

How to set the whole column to the index of the row?

```
  a b c d
1 1 3 3 1
2 2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6 7
4 6 5 7 8
```

becomes

```
  b c d
1 3 3 1
2 3 4 5
4 5 6 7
6 5 7 8
```

I have tried to use xts(), but the column type changed to character but not numeric

Comment: tried `row.names(df) <- df$a` ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you will show the code you used. try using `rownames(df) <- df$a`. it will still be string because row names are strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments here is a solution:

```
row.names(df) <- df$a
df <- df[-1] # To eliminate the column as "it is" now in the row.names
```

If you want to change to numeric, you can apply this function to convert it to numeric:

```
df <- apply(df, 2, as.numeric)
```